# Size() function compiliation error, says size() is not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, scope

Here is the header:

```
#ifndef SHIP_H
#define SHIP_H
class Ship
{
  public:
    virtual ~Ship(void) {}
    virtual const char *name(void) const = 0;
    virtual int size(void) const = 0;
    int getX(int i) const;
    int getY(int i) const;
    void print(void) const;
    bool includes(int x, int y);
    int level(void) const;
    void decreaseLevel(void);
    static Ship *makeShip(char ch, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
  protected:
    void setPos(int a1, int b1, int a2, int b2);
    int lev;
  private:
    bool checkConfig(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
    int x1,y1,x2,y2;
};

class AircraftCarrier : public Ship
{
  public:
    AircraftCarrier(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
    virtual const char *name(void) const;
    virtual int size(void) const;
};

class BattleShip: public Ship
{
  public:
    BattleShip(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
    virtual const char *name(void) const;
    virtual int size(void) const;
};

class Cruiser: public Ship
{
  public:
    Cruiser(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
    virtual const char *name(void) const;
    virtual int size(void) const;
};

class Destroyer: public Ship
{
  public:
    Destroyer(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
    virtual const char *name(void) const;
    virtual int size(void) const;
};
#endif
```

Here is my size function in one of the derived classes, all size function for each of the four classes is formatted the same, each with different size values:

```
int AircraftCarrier::size(void) const
{
    int size = 5;
    return size;
}
```

and here is where i use size which is where the error references:

```
bool checkConfig(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    //int s,spaces;
    //s = size();
    if (x1 == x2)
    {
        if(size()-1 == y2-y1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    else if (y1 == y2)
    {
        if(size()-1 == x2-x1)
        {
            return true
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: I would use a different name for the variable than the function...

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `Ship` scope in `getConfig`'s definition:

```
bool Ship::checkConfig(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{//  ^^^^^^
  ...
```

Without it, it is just a non-member function, and has no access to any of `Ship`'s members (such as `size()`.)

Comment: Wow can't believe I missed that, been staring at the screen too long, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
bool checkConfig(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
```

That is a free function, not a member function definition. Should that be:

```
bool Ship::checkConfig(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `checkConfig` is a free function. If this is the case, then it will be using the *free function `size()`* which is undefined. You must either make `checkConfig` a member function or pass, ideally a `Ship&` to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your `checkConfig` is a not a member of any class. It is a freestanding function. So in that context a standalone `size()` does not make any sense and will not compile.

`size()` is a member of your class. You need an object of your class, for which you will call `size()` by using `.` or `->` operators. For example, this is valid

```
AircraftCarrier a;
a.size();
```

but a mere `size()` in the middle of some completely unrelated code (like your `checkConfig`) will not compile. You cannot call `size()` without specifying a specific object.